# Trouble implementing scipy optimize minimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am facing a bit of trouble implementing `scipy.optimize.minimize()`.
It returns me with the error `ValueError: Objective function must return a scalar`. 
Here is my code:

```
def cost(A,b,x):
    return np.sum(np.square(np.dot(A,x)-b))

def sse(x):
    return 1-sum(x)

x0 = np.ones(4)/4
bounds = tuple((0,1) for x in x0)
cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': sse})
All = minimize(cost, x0, args=(A, curve), method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=cons).x
```

`A` has shape `(400,4)`, `curve` has shape `(400,)`, and `x` , `x0` have shape `(4,)`.

I seem to be missing out on something very trivial. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of your function to minimize needs `x` as first non-keyword parameter; then the others might follow.

(So internally your variable-mapping was wrong and therefore your shapes are producing a different result-shape which is not scalar)

I also don't see any use of `curve` in your code! Probably `curve = b`?

So just change:

```
def cost(A,b,x):  # WRONG
    return np.sum(np.square(np.dot(A,x)-b))

def cost(x, A, b):  # CORRECT
    return np.sum(np.square(np.dot(A,x)-b))
```

Comment: Thanks! Got it. Also, the `curve` is being passed to the `b` variable in the function.

Comment: Yes, but i would not like those different names. It's hard to follow imho.